# Returning only true boolean value JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, boolean

I would like to return JSON objects in javascript/typescript that have a true boolean value for "team". An example of the JSON I am using is:

```
{
    "state": "Texas",
    "stateId": 1,
    "team": true
},
{
    "state": "California",
    "stateId": 5,
    "team": false
},
{
    "state": "Rhode Island",
    "stateId": 14,
    "team": true
}
```

So it should return Texas and Rhode Island in an array. So far, I have written the following code but it does not take into consideration the different boolean values and I am unsure why:

```
jsonString: any;
stateArray: any;

constructor() {
this.jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
this.stateArray = JSON.parse(this.jsonString);

  this.stateArray.filter(function(array) {
  if (data["team"] === true) {
      return array;
  }
});

console.log(this.stateArray);
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)'s callback gets executed for every element of your array and expects a callback which takes single element as parameter and returns `boolean` value. Try:

```js
let stateArray = [{
    "state": "Texas",
    "stateId": 1,
    "team": true
},
{
    "state": "California",
    "stateId": 5,
    "team": false
},
{
    "state": "Rhode Island",
    "stateId": 14,
    "team": true
}]

let result = stateArray.filter(function(state) {
  return state.team;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi mickl thanks for your help, I tried your solution but it gives the same input. I edited my original post to show that in my function I have parsed JSON and stringified it beforehand. If you know a solution with this?

Comment: `filter` returns a new array so you have to assign that values somewhere (it won't modify existing one), try: `this.stateArray = this.stateArray .filter(...)`

Comment: I see, the code works now! Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score -1):

Even you can do it in one line by using the arrow operator of ES6.

Kindly find below code.

```js
let stateArray = [{
    "state": "Texas",
    "stateId": 1,
    "team": true
},
{
    "state": "California",
    "stateId": 5,
    "team": false
},
{
    "state": "Rhode Island",
    "stateId": 14,
    "team": true
}]

let result = stateArray.filter(state => state.team);

console.log(result);
```